# SessionFactory init null pointer spring 3+ hibernate 4+

Tags: spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

i have a weird problem spring is returning null when he is trying to init the sessionFactory.
I did not inject in my code it throw null when the context is init.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import fr.demo.bean.Client;
import fr.demo.service.dao.ClientDAO;

@Transactional
@Repository
public class ClientDAOImpl implements ClientDAO{

//  @Autowired
//  private SessionFactory  sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Integer create(Client obj) {
    return null;
    }
    @Override
    public void delete(Client obj) {
    }
    @Override
    public void update(Client obj) {
    }
    @Override
    public Client find(Integer id) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public List<Client> findAll() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And this is the error i have:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/resources/spring/database/DataSource.xml]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

I let u know that it when i write the mapping hibernate inside the sessionfactory i have this error.
so this is my mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name="client")
public class Client implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8707073906887139645L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;
    @Column(name="nom", nullable=false, length=100)
    private String nom;
    @Column(name="prenom", nullable=false, length=100)
    private String prenom;
    @Column(name="adresse", nullable=false, length=100)
    private String adresse;
    @Column(name="telephone", nullable=false, length=100)
    private String telephone;
    @Column(name="email", nullable=false, length=100)
    private String email;
    private String image;
 }
```

This is the servlet context:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd"> -->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.demo.service.web"/>
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/errors"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean"/>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass">
            <value>org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView</value>
        </property>
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <import resource="../database/DataSource.xml"/>
    <import resource="../database/Hibernate.xml"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="fr.demo.service.dao" />
</beans>
```

and the full trace

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/resources/spring/database/DataSource.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1488)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findLoadedResource(WebappClassLoader.java:3266)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoader.java:1480)
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    ... 33 more

May 11, 2013 1:37:55 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet spring-mvc
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.findLoadedResource(WebappClassLoader.java:3266)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoader.java:1480)
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:154)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1547)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:608)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

my datasource config bean:

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
        xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

        <!--  Declaration de la DATASOURCES -->
        <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location">
                <value>/WEB-INF/resources/properties/database.properties</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="datasource"
            class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
            <property name="driverClassName" value="${db.driverClassName}" />
            <property name="url" value="${db.url}" />
            <property name="username" value="${db.username}" />
            <property name="password" value="" />
        </bean>
        <!--  Declaration Session Factory -->
        <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
            <property name="mappingResources">
                <list>
                    <value>fr.demo.bean.Client</value>
                </list>
            </property>
            <property name="hibernateProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">
                        org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                    </prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">true</prop> 
                </props>
            </property>
        </bean>
        <bean id="transactionManager"
             class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
            <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="datasource" />
        </bean>
        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>

    </beans>
```

Comment: Show us the DataSource.xml file and the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: i edit my post with datasource/full trace, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with the following configuration:

```
<property name="mappingResources">
    <list>
        <value>fr.demo.bean.Client</value>
    </list>
</property>
```

The [javadoc for setMappingResources](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setMappingResources%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29) says:

> Set Hibernate mapping resources to be found in the class path, like "example.hbm.xml" or "mypackage/example.hbm.xml"

So your config tells Spring to look for a file named fr.demo.bean.Client in the root package, which is wrong. If you want to specify the name of an annotated class, use... [`annotatedClasses`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setAnnotatedClasses%28java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29)